# C# - Check a bool for a value and then flip it

Tags: c#, xor

```
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
   myitem = (checkedDB) ? dirtyItem : cleanItem;
```

I wanted to know if there's a way of flipping checkedDB in the same statement, i.e. the next iteration checkedDB is the opposite of it's value, so like XORing.

Comment: Interesting question: what language?  I don't know of anything like this in C#/Java/C++

Comment: XOR is just a bitwise operation — it isn't destructive. So this is not like XOR. It's like setting a variable and checking its logical negation.

Comment: checkedDB ^= checkedDB has the desired thing.

Comment: @halivingston, that will just zero-out the variable.

Comment: @Chuck, flipping the value of `checkedDB` is non-destructive too.

Comment: If you are doing this inside a for loop, you could just use (i%2==0) to get a value that flips on each iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about:

```
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
    myitem = !(checkedDB = !checkedDB) ? dirtyItem : cleanItem;
```

That may be not really readable/understandable at first sight, but it does what you want in one statement.

Comment: won't this flip the value first and then check the flipped value? i'm only guessing. sorry if i'm wrong. :)

Comment: `checkedDB = !checkedDB` will evaluate to `!checkedDB`, thus you should swap `dirtyItem` and `cleanItem` if it should be semantically equivalent to the formulation in the question.

Comment: Nope. It flips the value, sets the variable to that value, then checks against the value flipped again (i.e. the original value).

Comment: I think it's important to note that this is **not something you should ever voluntarily do**.

Comment: @Chuck: agreed. Thats everything else than clean code. It may look like `checkedDB == !checkedDB` at first sight. But it is just the answer to the OPs question.

Comment: @Philip: Yeah, I know. Like I said, I just think it's important to note that, although this is the best way to do what the OP is asking about, it's even better not to do it in the first place. Nothing against your answer.

Comment: meh never say never.  If your code is getting called 100 times a second never say never.

Answer (score 3):

The best answer, IMO, is: not if you have any self-respect. The result will be ugly and confusing, and for no real gain. Here are two distinct solutions that are cleaner and thus easier to understand.

```
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
    myitem = checkedDB ? dirtyItem : cleanItem;
    checkedDB = !checkedDB;
}
```

The following version doesn't even require the extra variable and achieves your one-line goal:

```
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
    myitem = i%2 == 0 ? dirtyItem : cleanItem;
}
```

Comment: Agreed. I should have given the OP that advice, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to toggle a boolean value is `bool ^= true`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
   myitem = (checkedDB ^= true) ? cleanItem : dirtyItem;
}
```

I swapped `cleanItem` and `dirtyItem` since you toggle `checkedDB` before one of them is chosen.

The benefit of using `checkedDb ^= true` over `checkedDB = !checkedDB` is that it is clear that you meant to modify `checkedDB` and didn't accidentally mistype a `==` comparison.

Since you haven't specified the language, I can't say for certain if your language will allow an assignment in the conditional part of the ternary operator.

Comment: C, C++, C# and Java all allow this, dont they? I am just guessing the OP meant one of these four.

Comment: What is the benefit of this over just doing `x = !x`?

Comment: I don't have a C# or Java compiler handy to test it, but C and C++ will certainly compile it.  Without testing it, I'm guessing C# would allow it since you aren't using a single `=`... Is there somewhere I can run a C# snippet online? :/

Comment: @Chuck: The benefit is that it is clear that your intent was a *modifying assignment*, not a typo where you intended to use an `==`.

Comment: Just tried it with c#: my code of the form `a = !(b = !b) ? t : f;` compiles and does the right thing, your `a = (b ^= true) ? t : f;` does also compile and does the trick, too.

Comment: Youre right, your method makes more clear that it wasnt a typo, however I think, swapping bools reads simpler with just the `!` operator. I guess both solutions are nice, small and inline, but both are not very nice with respect to maintainability/readability.

Comment: This is also preferable to avoid bugs from using not (or not) close to something of the same shape  -  if (!MyVariable)

Answer (score -1):

The following should work, but may not be easily understandable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
    myitem = (checkedDB = !checkedDB ) ? cleanItem : dirtyItem ;
```

I agree that there should be some better and cleaner solution in the future and I'd recommend something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
    myitem = (checkedDB^^) ? dirtyItem : cleanItem;
}
```